# Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'?. i am use python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I can't understand why this error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I am use python-3.6. The error occurs at this line:

```
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)
```

I am using a `.csv` file to obtain the data, which I got from this link: https://github.com/YoeriNijs/TweetAnalyzer

My code:

```
import nltk, random, csv, sys   
from nltk.corpus import names   
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize   
import nltk.classify.util   
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier   
from textblob import TextBlob`   

def selectTweets(row):
    tweetWords = []
    words = row[0].split()
    for i in words:
        i = i.lower()
        i = i.strip('@#\'"?,.!')
        tweetWords.append(i)
    row[0] = tweetWords

    if counter <= 499:
        trainTweets.append(row)
    else:
        testTweets.append(row)

trainTweets = []
testTweets = []


print ("Tweet Sentiment Analyzer by Yoeri Nijs")
print ("*" * 30)


while True:
    # Ask for filename
    filename =  str(input("> Please enter a filename (.csv): "))
    #Check if filename ends with .csv
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):

        try:

            #Open file
            with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

               #Print succes message
                print ("> File opened successfully!")

                counter = 0
                for row in reader:
                    selectTweets(row)
                    counter += 1

                print ("> Wait a sec for the results...")


                cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)

                print ('accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(c1, testTweets))
                c1.show_most_informative_features()
        except IOError:
            print ("File does not exist.")

    #Else if file does not end with .csv, do this
    else:
        print ("Please open a file that ends with .csv")`
```

This is the output I get:

```
Tweet Sentiment Analyzer by Yoeri Nijs<br>
******************************
Please enter a filename (.csv): data.csv<br>
File opened successfully!<br>
Wait a sec for the results...<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\Downloads\Compressed\TweetAnalyzer-master\TweetAnalyzer-master\script.py", line 63, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py", line 199, in train
    for fname, fval in featureset.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 0):

To train NLTK's `NaiveBayesClassifier` you need to pass the `train` method a dictionary as the first element in each list or tuple.  The dictionary contains the features as keys and the class as the value.  E.g.

```
trainTweets = [({'twitter': True,
                 'hashtag': False,
                 'retweet': True},
                'pos'),
               ({'trending': False,
                 'follow': False},
                 ...]
```

`NaiveBayesClassifier` then tries to access the dictionary values (`trainTweets.items()`) so it can learn the classes.  This is what throws the error because you've passed a list to the `train` method.

For more information, I suggest Sentdex's tutorial on using NLTK's `NaiveBayesClassifier` here:
https://pythonprogramming.net/words-as-features-nltk-tutorial/

Comment: i can,t solve this please help to do this.i am beginner. in the above my code and data you can find.please write the code where need too change